# Not able to export nodes from one drupal site to other drupal site?

Tags: 8, nodes, importing-exporting

I have 2 instances of same drupal project, where contents are different. I want to export contents from one drupal site to other drupal site.
I tried [content syn](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync) module:
      I Was not able import single node having file field value.
    [node_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module:
       Not able to import node

Anyone is having any idea, which is the best approach to transfer the contents between 2 drupal sites?

Error when tried with content sysn module:
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: No "file" entity found with UUID "514d82d9-e933-4be6-9dfb-3435b58d3531" for field "0". in Drupal\content_sync\Normalizer\EntityReferenceFieldItemNormalizer->constructValue() (line 88 of /var/www/html/drupal8/modules/contrib/content_sync/src/Normalizer/EntityReferenceFieldItemNormalizer.php).

Comment: Did you remenber to set up content sync dir in settings.php?

Comment: no,what we need to set....

Comment: Take a look at the answer